# How to show error message is record (Primary Key) already exists

Tags: vb.net

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class Reg
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

```
Dim sqlstring, ide, name, fname, cty, cpassw As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub submitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitbtn.Click
    ide = idbox.Text
    name = namebox.Text
    fname = fatherbox.Text
    cty = countrybox.Text

    cpassw = confirmpass.Text
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\DREAM THEATER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBAPP\APP_DATA\DATAAJIT.MDF;Integrated Security=True")
    myConn.Open()

    sqlstring = " INSERT INTO Test (Id,name,father,country,pass) VALUES (" + ide + ",'" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + cty + "','" + cpassw + "')"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Added Successfully !!!!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Insert !!")
    myConn.Close()
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")


End Sub
```

Given above is my code .
what line of code I have to add and where ?

Comment: @BillGregg everyone starts somewhere..

Comment: managing PKs is the job for the database.  Even lowly Access will handle these nuts and bolts for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a try catch to catch the exception.

For Example:

```
   Protected Sub submitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitbtn.Click
        ide = idbox.Text
        name = namebox.Text
        fname = fatherbox.Text
        cty = countrybox.Text

        cpassw = confirmpass.Text

        Try

        myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\DREAM THEATER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBAPP\APP_DATA\DATAAJIT.MDF;Integrated Security=True")
        myConn.Open()

        sqlstring = " INSERT INTO Test (Id,name,father,country,pass) VALUES (" + ide + ",'" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + cty + "','" + cpassw + "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Added Successfully !!!!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Insert !!")
        myConn.Close()
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occured: " & ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub
```

This will show a message box with the exception message that occured.

Comment: @BillGregg nope this is VB.net syntax. [MSDN - Try, Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)